# Why would sys.dm_exec_requests show a query in Database A blocking a query in Database B when neither query references the same tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, blocking, system-tables, waits

I have a query I use in-house to monitor slow running processes in the data layer. It essentially looks at a few fields from the following system tables and views joined in the following way:

```
SELECT ER.blocking_session_id, SP.DBID, EST.text, etc...
FROM sys.sysprocesses SP  
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests ER 
    ON sp.spid = ER.session_id 
CROSS APPLY SYS.DM_EXEC_SQL_TEXT(ER.[sql_handle]) EST
```

While using it to debug some slow processes I encountered the ER.blocking_session_id was stating Query1 in Database1 was being blocked by Query2 that runs in Database2 and both queries interact with completely different tables. Ironically, both queries also use NOLOCK hints everywhere (not my choice.)

Here's the example 2 queries.

Query1 (being blocked by Query2):

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable1
SELECT Field1, ISNULL(Field2, Field3) AS NewField
FROM Database1.Table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Database1.Table2 WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON Table1.Field4 = Table2.Field4
```

Query2 (doing the blocking):

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable2
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM Database2.DifferentTable1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Database2.DifferentTable2 WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON DifferentTable1.Field5 = DifferentTable2.Field5
```

The last few wait types I'm seeing for Query1 are: PAGELATCH_UP, IO_COMPLETION, CXPACKET.
For Query2 they're: PAGELATCH_UP, and CXPACKET.

I always interpreted that the sys.dm_exec_requests.blocking_session_id literally meant table locks, but is it possible it could refer to other types of blocks due to resource contention?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation for [dm_exec_requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for clues?

Comment: @LowlyDBA I have, but I don't see anything specific regarding the blocking_session_id field to clarify my interpretation of it. If you know of any specific section in there that does, please let me know.

Comment: `wait_type` indicates the *type* of blocking wait. So a non-locking based wait in that column would imply that blocking of the non-lock variety is indeed possible.

Comment: @LowlyDBA Ah very interesting. So what would the wait types I was seeing indicate in this case, ELI5 please.